# VMWare Workstation Sharing system

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation

I'm trying to share a vm with another computer, connected to mine (hosting the vm) via switch. 
I configured the vm sharing settings, and now I have a server in my pc that is hosting the vm. 
In the vm I have ubuntu, and I'm hosting a site with apache. Now.. I tried to enter  my site in the vm from my pc, with "localhost" instead to use the vm ip address.
Before to this, I could perfectly enter the site with the vm ip address. It worked, and works now too. Instead, if I try to access the site from my pc with "localhost", I can access only the apache index.html that says the server is running, but I CAN'T access the others site's files.... Idk why
And also i tried to enter my vm from other computer connected with a switch, and it can't see also the index.html of apache...
Can someone help me with the vm sharing?

Recaps: I have a vm in vmware workstation 15. The vm is hosting ubuntu 18.10, where there is installed apache hosting a site. I need to share this site with another pc in lan with the pc that has installed workstation, via switch.

Comment: To clarify: your host (and other PCs) can connect to the VM fine, but the Apache web server isn't showing the correct files?  Seems like an Apache configuration problem to me then.

Comment: What network settings are you using for the VM in Workstation, bridged, NAT, host-only, or a custom network?

Comment: @essjae I'm using NAT for my vm network setting.

Comment: @jamesdlin My host can connect to the vm, I can see the apache index.html "Server is working", but i can't see the other files in the server. From an external host I can't also see the apache index.html

Comment: Use bridged networking if you want external hosts to access your VM.  The rest of it is an Apache configuration issue.

Comment: It works on the host because of how NAT is configured with Workstation, both the host and VM are on the same subnet behind the NAT.  If you want external access to the VM, you'll want to use bridged networking, or set up port forwarding on the NAT's configuration through the Virtual Network Editor-->NAT settings.